# Forgot password: How can I send an email to user in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have made custom login control for DNN (DotNetNuke). Now I am trying to implement the forgot password feature. I am able to retrieve password from the database using the code:

```
UserInfo uInfo = UserController.GetUserByName(this.PortalId, userName);
if (uInfo != null)
{
    string password = UserController.GetPassword(ref uInfo, String.Empty);
}
```

I want to send the retrieved password to the user using DNN.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: as far as I know, is better not to send user his password (and it should be hashed, so you should NOT may retrieved it), but send him link to webpage where he can reset his password

Comment: The requirement is such that , I am left with no other option but to send it on email.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: @palakmehta - How does DNN protect a user's password using a hasing or encrypting method?  If its a hashing method then what you want is not possible.  If its an encryption method then it is possible.  Sending a user's password is NOT a good idea, it should NOT be possible for ANYONE to retreieve their password, doing so places the security of the website at risk.  If a normal user's password can be retrieved then an admin's account can also.  Hashing a password with a secure salt is the ONLY method you should use.  I al almost certain the developers of DNN know this.

Comment: @Ramhound :Thanks for your input.Passwords are stored in encrypted form in DNN.Though it's not advisable , but yes you can send it via email.
I have found the solution but stackoverflow.com is not permitting me to submit an answer .I am allowed to submit an answer only after 8 hours of my post.

Regards,
Palak.

Comment: Out of the box dnn passwords are encrypted, you can however choose to hash them instead by modifying the settings of the provider in the web.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending passwords via email is considered as a big security vulnerability and **really not recomended**.

If you still need this functionality though, I guess you can simply accomplish this by sending email through `SendMail` or `SendEmail` methods:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendEmail()
DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail()
```

The `SendMail` method provides more options/parameters than the `SendEmail` method. The paramters names should be self explanatory enough to use the methods.

Comment: I was about to write the same answer.Thanks @mnemcik.

Comment: You should correct your answer for a time saver, the correct reference is actually DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail() and DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendEmail() (notice the extra .Mail)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to send a user their password is to call the [`DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail`](http://dotnetnukeru.com/Dnn6Docs/api/html/M_DotNetNuke_Services_Mail_Mail_SendMail.htm) overload that takes a `UserInfo`, a [`MessageType`](http://dotnetnukeru.com/Dnn6Docs/api/html/T_DotNetNuke_Services_Mail_MessageType.htm), and `PortalSettings`.  You can pass in the user and `MessageType. PasswordReminder` and DNN will take care of the rest.

That said, I join the crowd in saying that it would be much better to [switch to using hashed passwords](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2011/10/07/securing-a-dotnetnuke-installation---passwords.aspx) and consider this an impossible feature request (that should, instead, be fulfilled with a password reset feature).